# NPM giving error - TypeError: Cannot destructure property `stat` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: npm, npm-install

when I type `npm` on `cmd`, I get error `TypeError: Cannot destructure property` stat `of 'undefined' or 'null'.`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
npm -v
```

and check whether npm is showing version or not !
If not then please try to install or if you already installed app then try to add path up to /bin in the environment variable. This will help you.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry but I uninstalled node and reinstalled it. This seem to solve the problem. I'll accept your answer as it might be the right one.